# When should we use a @property int variable and when a non property int variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c. I noticed that i can declare a

```
@property int nameOfVariable
```

as well as

```
int nameOfVariable
```

inside a class .h interface file.

Obviously one is declared as a property and the other one not as a property but i do not understand the difference and when should be used...any help appreciated.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html#_properties

Comment: Because i haven't used objective c for 6 years! I forgot everything! Everything changed in 6 years so i am newbie.

Comment: Can you give some examples of how would you use the two in a class definition?